# Hibernate One To Many Prepared Statement extremely slow

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have two Hibernate JPA model classes, Document and Document_Positions, which stand in a one to many relationship. Document maps to Document_Position as follows:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="document",  fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@OrderBy("pos ASC")
private Set<Document_Position> documentPositions=new HashSet<>();
```

This works ok, however, the query speed for the documentPositions set is really slow. I measured the time with Google stopwatch:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        documentp0_.art as art1_115_0_,
        documentp0_.firma as firma2_115_0_,
     […] 187 more columns
    from
        bcd.dbo.Document_Positions documentp0_ 
    where
        documentp0_.art=? 
        and documentp0_.firma=? 
        and documentp0_.nr=? 
    order by
        documentp0_.pos asc

Loading time 367.2 ms
```

Querying the same data with createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList() only takes about 2% of the time:

```
Hibernate: 
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        Document_Positions
    WHERE
        firma=1 
        AND art=2 
        AND nr='19-0000306' 
    ORDER BY
        pos ASC

Loading time 6.377 ms
```

It seems like the prepared statement syntax makes the difference. Things I have already tried with no effect:

- Change the mapping in the model from “mappedBy” to “JoinColumns”.
- A newer SQL Server dialect (unfortunately, there is no SQLServer2017Dialect)
- The Parameters sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false; and
  sendUnicode=false; in the connection string.
- Enable query caching.
- Removing the “ORDER BY” clause
- Using a list instead of a set.

Technical specifications:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2017 database
- Hibernate 5.4.9
- Microsoft JDBC Driver For SQL Server 7.2.1.jre8 (also tried with
  7.4.1.jre8 and 6.4.0.jre8)

Is there any way to fix the problem or a workaround?